# HSSFRichTextString styling disappear in print preview

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am facing issues in print preview with xls generated using apache POI. I have used HSSFRichTextString to apply styling to cell content.For text I`m applying Arial font  & for numbers within cell content i am using Terminal font.
E.g "SS 123 RR" SS/RR will be in Arial, 123 will be in Terminal.
Below is code snippet for the same.

```
package com.adp.wfn.payroll.exportToExcel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
public class ReadAndWriteRichText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("/home/devel/Desktop/hi/CheckRegister_Template.xls");
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(1);


        Font font1 = workbook.getFontAt(cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
        System.out.println(font1);

        Font font2 = workbook.createFont();
        font2.setFontName("Terminal");
        font2.setFontHeightInPoints(font1.getFontHeightInPoints());
        System.out.println(font2);
        String originalStr="ss 123  ss";    
        HSSFRichTextString richString = new HSSFRichTextString( "SS 123  SS    44" );


        cell.setCellValue( formatNumbersOfCellText(originalStr,font2,font1) );

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                        new File("/home/devel/Desktop/createworkbookRaj.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("createworkbook.xlsx written successfully");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
   }


private static HSSFRichTextString formatNumbersOfCellText(String outputString,Font numberFont, Font strFont){
    HSSFRichTextString formattedString = null;
    try{//"ss 123 nn 67"
        if(null != outputString && !outputString.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            int lstIndexCalculated=0;
            int startIndex ;
            int endIndex;
            String[] splittedArr = outputString.split("\\s");
            if(null != splittedArr && splittedArr.length > 0){
                formattedString = new HSSFRichTextString(outputString);
                for (int i = 0; i < splittedArr.length; i++) {

                        if(lstIndexCalculated == 0){
                            startIndex = outputString.indexOf(splittedArr[i]);
                        }else{
                            startIndex = outputString.indexOf(splittedArr[i],lstIndexCalculated);
                            if(lstIndexCalculated < startIndex){
                                formattedString.applyFont(lstIndexCalculated,startIndex ,numberFont);
                            }
                        }
                        endIndex   = startIndex + (splittedArr[i].length());
                        lstIndexCalculated = endIndex;
                        if(isNumericField(splittedArr[i])){
                            formattedString.applyFont(startIndex,endIndex ,numberFont);
                        }else{
                            formattedString.applyFont(startIndex,endIndex ,strFont);
                        }
                        startIndex = 0;
                        endIndex   = 0;

                }
                if(lstIndexCalculated != 0){
                    return formattedString;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
      return null;   
    }
    return null;

}


private static boolean isNumericField(String inputStr){
    if(null != inputStr && !inputStr.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        try{
            inputStr = inputStr.replaceAll("[(,)]", "");
            Double value = Double.valueOf(inputStr);
            return true;
        }catch(NumberFormatException numFormatExp){
            return false;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;

    }

}
```

Now when i open generated xls I see formatting applied to contents.
Please refer [xls view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnDll.png) for the same.
But now when i do print preview I see issue with font. Terminal font which applied for numbers is no longer visible in print preview. Please refer [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLf8f.png) for print preview view.
Note the difference between number '1' in both images.
Any idea/suggestion how do i overcome this ?
Thanks In advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `apache poi`. Even if you are creating the Excel sheet not using `apache poi` but with Excel itself you will see the same in print preview. The print preview is not for exact showing each single character but for showing the whole page setup.

Comment: No Axel with plain Excel and manually formatting values it works fine. Although print is showing page setup & not exact style but still its replica of how print will be. I took printout of excel & still see the issue with it. No styling.